# Unable to access records inserted from one test method to another method

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am working on a requirement to tag values from a case(one record type to another) to another case. But right now we don't have lookup fields in case level.

My apex class is working perfectly. But my test classes are working if any existing case is tagging while case creation.

Suppose in test class I'm creating an X case first. And updating this case number in another y case. If I am creating both cases on a single test class it is not working.

If i had created the account as well as x case first in the database with(seeall data) annotation it is working.

But i don't want to use this annoation.Is there any way to handle this situation.

Test class:

```
@istest(SeeAllData=true)
public class TestOrdertoRisk {
    Static Profile standardProf = [select id from profile where name='Standard User'];
    Static User su = new User(alias = 'standt', email='ARPUTest@azugacase.com',emailencodingkey='UTF-8',FirstName='ARPU',
                           lastname='Testing',languagelocalekey='en_US',localesidkey='en_US',
                           profileid = standardProf.Id,timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',
                           username='ARPUTest@azugacase.com');
    Static Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order'].Id;
    Static Id Churnrecordtypeid= [Select id from RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Churn_Retention'].Id;
    //Static case c1=new case();
    //Static account a=new account();
    static testmethod void TestARPUInsert()
    {   
        System.runAs(su){
        Account a =new Account(Name='Internal TestARPU');
        insert a;
        List<Case> ARPUCases =new List<Case>();
        Id account =[Select id from account where name=:'Internal TestARPU'].id;
        Case c3 = new Case(AccountId =a.id,Status='New',RecordTypeId=Churnrecordtypeid,Assigned_Group__c='Risk Group',
                               Case_Assigned_Staff__c='Nina Javier',Case_Category__c='Account Related',Case_Type__c='Churn',
                               Case_Subtype__c='Hard Churn',Case_Reason_New__c='Product - Device',Vehicle_Make_model__c='Test',
                               Vehicle_Year__c='1996',Subject='Churn_Case_Check',Main_Case_Reference__c='12345');
        Boolean errorThrown = false;
            try {
                insert c3;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug(e);
                if (e.getMessage().contains('There is no case associated with this number')) {
                    errorThrown = true;
                }
            }
            System.assert(errorThrown);     
            Case c1 = new Case(AccountId =a.ID,Status='New',RecordTypeId=recordTypeId,Origin='Internal',
                               Case_Details__c='Hard Churn',Churn_under_180_days__c='No',Reason_for_Churn__c='Product - Device',
                               Revenue_effective__c=Date.today(),Azuga_Invoice_no__c='1234',Rate_Plan_type_for_Case__c='Azuga G2 Flex',
                               Date_Order_Received__c=Date.today(),Contract_Term__c=1,Subscription_Rate__c=19.99,
                               Payment_No__c='20',FSS_Rep__c='Francis Xavier',X3G_VZW_CDMA_OBD2_US_ONLY__c=-5,
                               Subscription_Amendment_No__c='Yes',Order_Signup_date__c=Date.today(),Trial_units_billed_in_this_order__c='No',LGS_Rep__c='NA');
                insert c1;  
    }
    }
    Static testmethod void TestChurnRetention()
    {
        Id details=[Select id from account where name='Internal TestARPU'].id;
        String cssp=[Select id,Casenumber from case where RecordTypeId=:recordTypeId AND accountid=:details LIMIT 1 ].Casenumber;
        System.debug('Case DEtails '+cssp);
            //System.debug('casenumber from directly '+c1.casenumber);
            //System.debug('Account details'+a.id);
        //System.debug('Case MRR '+c1.Total_order_MRR__c);
        //Integer count=database.countQuery('select count() from case where casenumber=:cssp');
        //System.debug('Case Count'+count);
            Case c2 = new Case(AccountId =details,Status='New',RecordTypeId=Churnrecordtypeid,Assigned_Group__c='Risk Group',
                               Case_Assigned_Staff__c='Nina Javier',Case_Category__c='Account Related',Case_Type__c='Churn',
                               Case_Subtype__c='Hard Churn',Case_Reason_New__c='Product - Device',Vehicle_Make_model__c='Test',
                               Vehicle_Year__c='1996',Subject='Churn_Case_Check',Main_Case_Reference__c=cssp.trim());
            If(c2<> null )
            {
                Test.startTest();
                insert c2;
                Test.stopTest();
            }
        System.debug('Date order info'+c2.Date_Order_Received__c);
            decimal css=[Select id,Total_order_MRR__c from case where id=:c2.id].Total_order_MRR__c;
            System.assertEquals(-99.95, css);
        }                 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any test data to which you require access across test cases should be built in an [`@testSetup` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testsetup.htm).

Each unit test executes in an isolated environment and has no access to data created by or updated by other unit tests. As a consequence, you cannot use Test Method A's execution to set up the conditions for Test Method B. The test setup method's results, however, are available at the start of each unit test.

Note that your unit tests still must query for their test records. All variables, including `static` variables, are reset between the execution of the `@testSetup` method and each test method.

Answer (score 1):

If you see [Understanding Test Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data.htm), it mentions:

> Apex test data is transient and isn’t committed to the database.
>
> This means that after a test method finishes execution, the data inserted by the test doesn’t persist in the database.

That means that anytime you create a test data in one test method, it does not exist to be used in another test method.

To resolve this, you will need to use [`@TestSetup`](http://Using%20Test%20Setup%20Methods) so that data created in the setup method is available in all of the test methods for that particular test class.

> Use test setup methods (methods that are annotated with `@testSetup`) to create test records once and then access them in every test method in the test class.

Take a look at the docs for more details as how you can utilize this to setup your data and access across your test methods.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I think OP is on the right track as it is mentioned in the question that OP does not prefer to use the annotation. So as long as OP can create test data, should be all good.